# How to use if else statements within for loops within PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I run through my dataframe and edit the data based on another column?

```
for people in andrew_lewis:
    if andrew_lewis['MRR'] == 'KC2':
        andrew_lewis['payout'] * 100
    else:
        print('wrong')
```

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be obvious, but you can use numpy's magic indexing to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    ['abc', 100],
    ['KC2', 200],
    ['def', 300],
    ['KC2', 400]
]
df = pd.DataFrame( data, columns=['MRR','QTY'] )
df.loc[df['MRR']=='KC2','QTY'] = df[df['MRR']=='KC2']['QTY'] * 100
print(df)
```

So, that selects specific rows with one column.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are trying to do is set the the value for the column `payout` to itself times 100 when the column `MRR` is 'KC2'. If that's not the case, then, well, I've probably got the wrong answer here.

To do this, you need a statement where you have `andrew_lewis['payout'] = ...`, with the `...` to be figured out. For that, you want it to be one thing when a condition is met and another thing when the condition is not met. You can use `numpy.where` for this.

```py
import numpy as np

andrew_lewis['payout'] = np.where(
    andrew_lewis['MRR'] == 'KC2',
    andrew_lewis['payout'] * 100,
    andrew_lewis['payout'])
```

`np.where` is helpful in that it doesn't require any loop over the dataframe, but handles this itself (and more efficiently). It will return an array, and we set that array to just overwrite our original dataframe column.

It takes three parameters:

1. Condition: we want to test if the value in a column 'MRR' is 'KC2'
2. True result: what we give when the condition is true. You want it to give the value of 'payout' (in the same row) times 100
3. False result: what we give when the condition is false. Just give the original value of 'payout'.

You should try real hard to avoid using for-loops with dataframes. I won't say they are never necessary (other people may say that and be right), but you can almost always do what you are trying to do with `np.where`, `np.choose`, `pd.df.apply`, or another `numpy` and `pandas` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`mask` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['KC1', 10],
     ['KC2', 20],
     ['KC2', 30],
     ['KC3', 40]],
    columns=['MRR','payout'])

df["payout"] = df["payout"].mask(df["MRR"]=="KC2", df["payout"]*100)

print(df)
```

```
# result

   MRR  payout
0  KC1      10
1  KC2    2000
2  KC2    3000
3  KC3      40
```